# Showing that $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi, \zeta) : \mathbb{Q}] = pq$ Wwth $(p,q) = 1$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\left [\mathbb{Q}[\xi] : \mathbb{Q} \right] = p$ and $[\mathbb{Q}[\zeta] : \mathbb{Q}] = q$.  Assume $gcd(p,q) = 1$.  Show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi, \zeta) : \mathbb{Q}] = pq$.

1. The notation above implies that both $\mathbb{Q}[\xi]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$ are fields and hence $\mathbb{Q}[\xi] = \mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ as well as $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta] = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
2. **Idea:** Use the towering lemma. That is, since $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\xi] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\xi][\zeta] = \mathbb{Q}[\xi,\zeta] = \mathbb{Q}(\xi, \zeta)$ under field inclusion, we have that

   $$
   [\mathbb{Q}[\xi, \zeta]: \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}[\xi][\zeta]: \mathbb{Q}[\zeta]] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}[\zeta] : \mathbb{Q}] = pq 
   $$
3. So now the goal becomes to show that $[\mathbb{Q}[\xi][\zeta]: \mathbb{Q}[\zeta]] = p = [ \mathbb{Q}[\xi] : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Why must this be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for simplicity write $\mathbb{Q}=K$,$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta,\xi)=L$. (Note that as well as reducing the amount of writing we have to do, this statement is also true for any two finite extensions of a field $K$ and this gives a general proof of that.)

Using the tower law as you mention, we get:

$[L:K]=[L:K(\zeta)]q=[L:K(\xi)]p$

Since $(p,q)=1$ we must have that $q|[L:K(\xi)]$ and so $q\leq[L:K(\xi)]$.

But clearly $[L:K(\xi)]\geq q$ since the degree of this extension is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $K(\xi)$ which is less than or equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $K$ (which we have defined to be $q$) since $K\subset K(\xi)$. Thus we must have equality, as desired.